# C# Textbox limit entered character and shortcut

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, textbox, keyboard-shortcuts

I am doing exercises and I come up with a problem I will be happy if someone help me and enlighten.

`button1` writes `1` into the `texbox1` but I want to limit the number of characters that one person can write and in this example I want to limit at 4 character. Which means one can enter no more than 4 character.

PROBLEM IS: when I click on the `textbox1` properties and change the `MaxLength` property it works if I enter characters via the keyboard but when set the `textbox1` to readonly, then it does NOT work. I can enter as many `1` as I can when I click the `button1`.

WHAT CAN I DO? I want to make the `textbox1` readonly and want to write max 4 character when I press `button1`.

And  QUESTION 2 is : I want to make `button1` press when I press the enter key on my keyboard. Thanks in advance.

here is my code

```
namespace formlar
{
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //textBox1.Text += textBox1.Text = "1";
        textBox1.Text += "1";
    }
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: If that's the problem inside that pink box screeny, then PLEASE just cut and paste it into the question, there's no way I'm reading that.

Comment: Please post your question in a readable format.

Comment: At times we ask for the relevant code for the problem faced, this way its the other way round, What is the problem ?

Comment: ok thanks edited. i thought that uploaded image was readable.

Comment: i vote up all the people that replies but why you people give minus if its cuz u couldnt read i edited. sorry its cuz im new.

Comment: @marc_s  thanks for nice editing. but people gave me minus because of the format. i did this in hurry and didn't realized that the image was not readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the documentation it says

[MaxLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength.aspx)

> Gets or sets the maximum number of characters that can be manually
>   entered into the text box.

So if you want to restrict in the code you will have to add that check and then stop the addition part.

Set the [`AcceptButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx) property of the current form to the `Button` you want

Comment: thanks alot for informing about the text box and i got you abut the AcceptButton property and yes it worked but what if i want to put a shortcut like F1 key or ctrl key and plus key A on the keyboard? i want to put a shortcut button for button1 like F1 or ctrl A

Comment: do you know how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

try this to limit string length:

```
        if (TextBox1.Text.Length < 4) TextBox1.Text += "1";
```

Comment: thanks rumburak.pl it solved. and i voted u up. as i voted V4Vendetta up also. but i think i will accept V4Vendetta answer because he give info about the textbox itself behaviour and replied the second question also. so do not be sad. i really thank you.